# Adding key in catch block on KeyNotFoundException Java

Tags: java, exception, hashmap

Is there any way to catch the `KeyNotFoundException` in Java `HashMap` and add the key to the map in catch block?

For example, I want to add a value to the key in `HashMap`. If that key is not present, then `KeyNotFoundException` will be thrown.

One alternative is to each time check if the key exists. If it doesn't, add the key and then add the value. If it exists, directly add the value to the key. However, there will be lots of overhead with the if conditions. So, when this exception is thrown, can I add the key and value in the catch clause and then proceed properly?

Comment: If a key isn't found in a HashMap, not exception is thrown, it simply returns null?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that isn't real.

Comment: There is no KeyNotFoundException

Answer (score 2):

If the key does not exist, `map.put(key,value)` would simply add it with its value. If the key exists, `map.put(key,value)` would overwrite the old value. Either way, no exception will be thrown. Why would you want to throw an exception?

If you want to change the current value when the key is already present, it would be better to check if the key exists and add it if not. Otherwise, you would still have to check if the key exists (either with `!map.containsKey(key)` or `map.get(key)==null`) in order to know when to throw the exception, and you would still have to write the logic that adds the key in the catch block, so you won't save anything, and your code will only become less readable.

Answer (score 1):

You are 100% mistaken about all this.

> Is there any way to catch the `KeyNotFoundException` in Java `HashMap`

No, because there is no such exception in Java.

> and add the key to the map in catch block?

No, because you can't even compile such code,

> For example, I want to add a value to the key in hashmap. If that key is not present, then `KeyNotFoundException` will be thrown.

No it won't.

> One alternative is to each time check if the key exists.

With `Map.containsKey()`.

> If it doesn't, add the key and then add the value.
>
> If it exists, directly add the value to the key. But, there will be lots of overhead with the if conditions.

No there won't. `HashMap` is *O(1)* for key operations.

> So, when this exception is thrown,

'This exception' isn't thrown. It doesn't even exist.

> can I add the key and value in catch clause and then proceed properly?

No, because you can't compile the code.

Your question is founded on false premisses.